# Base_url to call outer css on codeigniter 3

Tags: css, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have structured like this

```
ci3
 -application
 -assets
    -css
      -home
        -main.css
    -fonts
      -home
      -icon
        -font-awesome
```

I have some trouble, in main.css to call font-awesome.
How to call it? Actually, this is my code :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('???');  //how to call it ?
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In view of CSS code, you can go three directories/folders back and then navigate to your font-awesome file. Checkout for the extension.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../../../fonts/icon/font-awesome');  /* Go to assets folder */
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```